# How to remove white space on the right of my hamburger menu

Tags: css

As you can see on the screenshots below, my hamburger menu overlaps with my logo, which would not happen if the hamburger menu was aligned to the right.

I've noticed that the fact that it was not aligned to the right was due to the line `"right: 68px;"` but without it I cannot place the `content: "--> menu"` to the left of the hamburger.

How can I fix this?

Many thanks,

```
.navbar-toggle::after {
    color: #000;
    content: "→ Menu";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    right: 68px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -21px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<header class="navbar boxed js-navbar">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="brand" href="index.html">
        <img alt="" src="images/logo.png">
        <div class="brand-info">
          <div class="brand-name">John Livingstone</div>
          <div class="brand-text">activity desc</div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div class="social-list hidden-xs">
        <a href="" class="icon ion-social-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href="" class="icon ion-social-linkedin" target="_blank"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-spacer hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>

      <address class="navbar-address hidden-sm hidden-xs">Blablabla header</span></address>

    </header>
```

[image]

Comment: how help to you without html code?share it please.

Comment: Hi - I have now added the HTML, but probably best if you see it live using the link in my post. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to fix your first problem you should a fixed width for the button. 25px seems fitting for me. But if you do that you'll encounter some other problems, because the button is done very strange semantically. If you change the pseudo ::after class to have a fixed width as well, it should work fine.

```
.navbar-toggle::after {
    color: #000;
    content: "→ Menu";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    right: 80px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -21px;
    width: 80px;
    display: block;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
}
```

But I would advise you to remove the "Menu ->" entirely, as normally the hamburger is enough to indicate navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I just added text to my own hamburger menu, but did it like this:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span>Menu</span>
```

then styled the last span as needed. Is that a possibility?